# What is GameKit development?

Tags: iphone, ipad

what is gamekit framework in iphone 4.0? can we develop individual game applications using it instead of cocos2d framework?

Comment: GameKit is simply Apple's "BAAS -lite".  It allows you to keep high-score tables online.  It has absolutely nothing to do with actually *making* a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GameKit and cocos2d serve totally different purposes. cocos2d are for drawing graphics, while [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is to support social gaming (Game Center, P2P connection, Voice Chat).

> Game Kit offers features that you can use to create great social games. Social games allow players to share their experiences with other players. When players tell their friends about their favorite games, this encourages more players to download and play those games. Positive word-of-mouth provides the best kind of free advertising to your game — happy customers.
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Art/gamekit_introduction.jpg))</sub>

You can use both together.